# Spark change line number

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I have a question that there is a file like
[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKJLF.png)
The first number of each line is the line number, the others are sets.
I just need to change the line number, for example , all line number plus 1 change to
[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltd0R.png)
What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, RDDs and Dataframes are immutable, meaning you can't change them. What you can do is apply transformations and create new ones.

By the sound of it you want to apply `map` which will allow you to transform each row as you see fit. This is a very basic transformation for which you can find countless examples in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read your data into a dataframe first,
Then just do a transformation on the first column by adding 1 to it

```
val df = spark.read....
val df1 = df.withColumn("firstcolumn", $"firstcolumn"+1)
df1.show
```

For example

```
scala> val df = Seq((0,1),(1,2),(2,3)).toDF("c1","c2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: int, c2: int]

scala> df.show
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+


scala> df.withColumn("c1",$"c1"+1).show
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val s = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\scala\\txt\\firstPic.txt").getLines.toList
val s1 = s.map(x=>x.split(" ").toList).map(v=>v.map(_.toInt)).
         map{case Nil => Nil; case h::t => h+1::t}
```

After that we can construct dataframe from list `s1`

***Test in REPL:***

```
scala> val s = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\scala\\txt\\firstPic.txt").getLines.toList
s: List[String] = List(0 1 3 4, 1 2 5 7 8, 2 3 4, 3 1)
scala> val s1 = s.map(x=>x.split(" ").toList).map(v=>v.map(_.toInt)).map{case Nil => Nil;case h::t => h+1::t}
s1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 3, 4), List(2, 2, 5, 7, 8), List(3, 3, 4), List(4, 1))

scala> s.foreach(x=>println(x))
0 1 3 4
1 2 5 7 8
2 3 4
3 1

scala> s1.foreach(x=>println(x.mkString(" ")))
1 1 3 4
2 2 5 7 8
3 3 4
4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pattern matching..

```
scala> val a = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.txt").getLines.toList
a: List[String] = List(0 1 3 4, 1 2 5 7 8, 2 3 4, 3 1)

scala> val pat = "(^\\d+)(.+)".r
pat: scala.util.matching.Regex = (^\d+)(.+)

scala> val c = a.map(p=> p match { case pat(x,y) => x.toInt+1+y } )
c: List[String] = List(1 1 3 4, 2 2 5 7 8, 3 3 4, 4 1)

scala> c.foreach(println)
1 1 3 4
2 2 5 7 8
3 3 4
4 1

scala>
```